# Interpolate values in 2D space + time (3D interpolation) of multiple objects in concert

Tags: interpolation

With a given dataset, I have multiple objects that move, in concert, inside a 2D eucledian space. The dataset of one object is given like this:

```
frame x   y
0     10  22
1     NaN  NaN
2     26  14
...
8999  54  45
9000  59  43
```

To keep the system fluidity, I want to interpolate all objects in concert with each other. This is necessary, because the objects are body parts, and it wouldn't make any sense if the left ear was placed on the same coordinate as the tail at the identical frame/time.

Any ideas on a solution?

Comment: How much do you know about interpolation? What is your dataset like, in more detail? Is it 3 dimensional (2 space dimensions + time)?

Comment: Very little, although I don't understand how that is relevant. It is 2 space dimensions and they have basis in frames, which is proportional to time, 30fps. So yes, 2 space dimensions + time

Comment: I only asked in case you knew more than myself, in which case I would refrain from giving advice, as I also know little about interpolation. In any case, 3d interpolation is very complicated...

Comment: You could start from here and see if anything seems fitting for your application https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_interpolation